# Inspecting type parameter of method in C#

Tags: c#

I'm working with a generic `PostAsync()` method that handles all API calls which looks like this:

```
public async Task<TResponse> PostAsync<TRequest, TResponse>(string url, TRequest data)
{
   // Handle API call
}
```

How do I inspect the `TResponse` parameter type to see if it's `null` or of a particular object type?

Comment: It cannot be null. How should that work? `PostAsync<MyRequest,null>(...`? And of a specific type - wouldn't that make using generics a little bit less make sense? But it is possible.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to do with pseudo code?

Comment: During debugging or when running the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're implementing this method:

`TResponse` isn't a parameter, there isn't anything to inspect. It's part of the signature saying that this method will return a `TResponse`.

If you mean you're calling this method:

`TResponse` has no constraints (at least at the method level, it might at the class level), so it could be null (unless you're have nullables enabled and then since it's not `TResponse?` it's not null) and could be of any type. You would need to use standard reflection methodology to ascertain what it's underlying type is. Checking for null would be as simple as

```
var foo = await PostAsync<Bar>("someUrl", data);
if (foo is null) ....
```